# Schema Migration from MySQL to MS SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I was trying to migrate MySQL 8.0.17 (Community Server) database to SQL Server 2019 using SSMA. After creating report, lot of error have been shown like unable index creation, unsupported function. Unfortunately almost all store procedures and functions have been shown as error conversion.How can i fix this issues? Should I write all SP and functions manually in SQL Server and validate all that those are running in SQl Server? As far as I understand, SSMA doesn't work properly with SP and function.

Comment: What is SSMA? SQL Server Migration Assistant? What is SP?

Comment: I'm not aware of any tools that can convert stored procedures between any rdbms. You must re-implement your stored procedures manually.

Answer (score 0):

SSMA will attempt to convert your views and stored procedures, but it can't translate 100% of the syntax, and even where it can the resulting TSQL might require manual review or revision.

SSMA will move the tables and data, and gives you a platform to fix and migrate your stored procedures.